# Whats wrong with this preg_match code?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to find the text between HTML tags:

```
<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">Here is a short text</td>
```

So I tried:

```
if(preg_match('#<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">(.*?)</td>#s',$result)) { ... }
```

But it gives me as result an exclamation mark (!).

What is wrong with my preg_match code?
Thank you for you help!

phpheini

Comment: I tested it and it works. It's `preg_match($pattern, $subject, $result);`- maybe wrong list of parameters?

Comment: What is `$result`? Is it the HTML string above?

Comment: No, $result is the array, that preg_match is writing the results in! So afterwards I should be able to get my results with echo $result[1];
The only possible thing is, that in the HTML code there are blanc spaces like <td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">        here is the text

So maybe preg_match doesnt check it?

Comment: Then where is the subject? You are only providing two arguments..

Comment: You are right, my mistake. $result is not the array, where the result is written, but the array, where html code should be searched in. So the problem was that I didnt put the array for the results of preg_match into the function.
So, now it works, thank you for you help!!!

Comment: Another problem though: Now, that I got the result, I realized that there are several hits for the search pattern in my html code. So I need to do enlarge my pattern like this:
if(preg_match('#<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">(.*?)</td></tr><tr><td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">#s',$result,$array)) { ... }

But now no result is returned. The problem might be, that there are empty spaces between the html tags. 
I read, that the letter "m" needs to be used. But I dont know how.

Comment: Why do we answer you? You even not choose Shikiryu as true answer.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know you could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is good : http://regexr.com?2t14i

```
if(preg_match('#<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">(.*?)</td>#s',
'<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">Here is a short text</td>')) { ... }
```

should work.